# Unable to connect to MySql from Node.js client using .my.cnf in home directory

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following in my **.my.cnf file in my home directory**. Actually I will have more entries for other databases too with different suffixes to 'client'. But, for now, to test, I have a simple .my.cnf file as in:

```
   [client]
   database=db1
   user=user1 
   password=user123
   host=localhost
```

In my Nodejs program, I use the following connection parameters:

```
var dbConn  = { 
    user: 'user1',
    database: 'db1'
};
```

I expect it to connect because the password is in .my.cnf. It does not, gives the following error:

```
 code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
 errno: 1045,
 sqlMessage: 'Access denied for user \'user1\'@\'localhost\' (using password: NO)',
  sqlState: '28000',
```

If I put the password in the connection object dbConn, it works. If I run mysql command line without specifying password, I am able to connect by using the password in .my.cnf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait. You just wrote the .cnf file separately. This wouldn't work. NodeJS wouldn't pick it up automatically. You need to use it with mysql connector. For example:

```
var ini = require('node-ini');
var mysql= require('mysql');

var config = ini.parseSync('/path/to/your/.my.cnf');

mysql.createPool({
                user: config.user,
                password: config.password,
                database: 'db1'
});
```

1. Source: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1676#issuecomment-289247509
2. node mysql - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: Thanks. I was on to this solution based upon a previous answer added but now deleted.  The node-ini package is too much for this. I just wrote a simple parser for the limited and simple .my.cnf file configuration I need to use.

Comment: I have tried this but cant find the file in the directory.
@Sunny can you help with the simpler solution that you tried ?

Comment: @ishmam999 Which file can you not find?